# Offline language translator API for Android?

Tags: android, translate

Is there any offline language translator API free to use for Android? Google provides one but I'm pretty sure you must connect to Google Play Services..

Comment: did my answer answer your question @Anggrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this one works: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454949.aspx

I got this one online and it doesn't require google play services. I hope this answers your question.